# Android app crash for missing class

Tags: java, android

I use Android sDK and i have this manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.deomanapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.deomanapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

but my application crash on start and the logcat said :

```
04-22 03:48:29.770: E/AndroidRuntime(2307): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.deomanapp.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.deomanapp-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.deomanapp-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]
```

I search for a while and find out this error usualy occare when you don't put Activity in manifest, but my manifest have this activity.How could i correct it?

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project? Also, try replacing `com.example.deomanapp.MainActivity` by `.MainActivity`

Comment: Are you compiling it in? I expect this class doesnt exist in the apk for whatever reason

Comment: @Sree Thank restarting solve my problem, but why ?

Comment: the issue is with building the app, check whether your have enabled the auto build. By restarting you are rebuilding the whole app.